# How do you address IO mapped using 36 bits?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, memory-management

I have a board with an APM86290(ppc) SOC on it.  This is my first foray into this type of development and I'm trying to work with the SPI controller which is mapped using a 36bit address(according to the datasheet).  I want to read some of the registers using `mmap()` and `/dev/mem`.  Is there normally a uniform way to address those high four bits?  Or is this likely something specific to this processor/[compiler](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/)? This is how I was attempting to do it now.

```
#define OFFSET 0xfa0000000 

int main()
{
    int i;
    unsigned int * someRegister;

    int fd = open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR|O_SYNC);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
            printf("Can't open /dev/mem\n");
            return 1;
    }
    someRegister = (unsigned int *) mmap(0, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, OFFSET);
    if(someRegister <= NULL)
    {
            printf("Can't mmap\n");
            return 1;
    }
    else
    {
            printf("register=%x\n",OFFSET);
            printf("contents=%x\n",*someRegister);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program returns these errors

> Machine check in kernel mode.
>      Instruction Read PLB Error
>      PLB Master Port Request Error
>      PLB read error 0x11000000 at 0x00000000_00000000

I thought maybe it wasn't using the 36bit addresses and truncating something, but When I do a `cat /proc/iomem`

```
effff8000-effffffff : ocm_mem
fa0000000-fa000001f : serial
```

Which show the 36 bit values I'm expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a lot on your setup. There's a 64-bit version of mmap() that you could try: [mmap64()](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html). If that won't work for you, you may need to map an upper and lower register for each 36-bit register.

Comment: The mmap64() appears to be retrieving what I want.  I spent the better part of the day banging my head against the wall... Thanks!

Comment: @Andy : FWIW, googling `"36-bit" "mmap"` brings up this suggestion multiple times in the first page. ;-]